# How to balance enemies in BESM 4e?

Tags: balance, monster-design, besm, besm-4e

I'm only somewhat experienced in DMing, and decided to run a game of Big Eyes Small Mouth 4th edition. I've started world building around the other characters, and during creation I found that one of the characters can deal 44 damage on a hit. While I'm not worried (yet) about him overpowering the other characters, how would I go about making enemies to fight the group if they can deal that much damage? Do I just make them at higher point pools? Or should I just ignore point pools to a certain extent?

I ask because of how open the system is and how few generic monsters and npcs are given in the system compared to D&D 5e, which I'm more experienced in, in comparison.

The main thing I'm worried about is enemies not having enough health and just dying in 2 hits.

Comment: Hi LaucianScout, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and visit the [help] for more information. This is a nice first question, but it might help answerers if you can give a little more detail about the other characters you need to balance for. Is this one character an outlier or is this typical for the group? Is there something about the system that makes you think this will be a problem? Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Hi and thanks for the welcome!

I'm not 100% on the other characters since some math still has to be done and 1 still has to be made, but I believe 3/4 of them should be around the same combat-wise (the 4th one being more out of combat oriented than in combat oriented). I was more curious how I'd go about enemy creation in general.

Answer (score 1):

Every BESM version I've played (2 and 3, but 4 is very similar), has been very susceptible to characters with wildly powerful attacks. I've found that I've needed to combine specifically accounting for those abilities in planning, be willing to fudge stats, be willing to lose enemies early, and play into genre conventions.

**Planning:** Just as BESM allows for wildly powerful attacks, it also has huge defensive powers: Absorption, Armor and Force Field, Dynamic Powers, Mulligan, Regeneration, Reincarnation, Resilient, Swarm, and so on. You can pick abilities for enemies that mitigate the enormous damage. Make sure not to make the player feel like they wasted their damage; perhaps there can be some enemies that they can destroy and others that counter their abilities so that the other players will have to take care of those.

**Fudging:** In the moment of play, I've certainly given enemies some extra Health or Energy if they're going down too quickly, or declared that the enemy fled or surrendered if the fight was dragging on too long. Some GMs consider this underhanded, but I think it's best to prioritize the player experience over rigid adherence to planning.

**Killing Darlings:** Sometimes enemies will be defeated unexpectedly. I've run a fight where the main adversary, the driver of a hypertech car, was dogpiled and taken out early. It turned out that his sidekick, a sniper who I intended to be his support, was a much more challenging opponent, and it became interesting story. Be willing to let the players unexpectedly destroy your characters.

**Genre Conventions:** BESM is an anime game. Anime is full of grunts that get defeated in one hit, challengers that lose an early fight and come back stronger, and powerful attacks that turn out to be ineffective against the next big bad enemy. You can let the group wipe the floor with enemies sometimes; if you need to, you can just bring any enemies back with new enhancements or training. If you overcompensate and make the enemies too strong, you can even have the PCs get defeated and have to train for the rematch. It will feel fun and genre-appropriate.